# Blackberry screen does not scroll back all the way

Tags: blackberry, scroll

I have an app which is displaying a news screen with app banner and title + image + details (RichTextField) and an Ad banner on the bottom of the screen so once I scroll down to read the details I can't get back to the top ..  it stops on the middle of the screen as you see in these pictures ..I don't know why .. it works perfectly when you use the touch on touch screen devices

[image: before scrolling]

[image: after scrolling back with the trackwheel]

here's my code for this screen ... please help

```
public class DetailsScreen_en extends MainScreen {

AppManager appManager;
private Detailsbean_en bean;
private AppManager manager;
private BitmapField bitmapField;
private LabelField titleField;
private LabelField dateField;
private RichTextField articleField;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private BitmapField bar;
private HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
Adsbean[] adsBean;
BitmapField ad;
VerticalFieldManager otherStuff;
VerticalFieldManager vvv;
Timer time;
TimerTask task;
private HorizontalFieldManager admanager;
private int adCounter = 0;
private boolean status;
private int tour;

public DetailsScreen_en(boolean status, int tour) {
    appManager = AppManager.getInstance();
    adsBean = appManager.getAdsBean();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_en));
    // ScreenOne.showLoadingScreen();
    this.status = status;
    this.tour = tour;
    XYEdges padding = new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10);
    HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser();

    vvv = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL
            | Field.FOCUSABLE) {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setExtent(maxWidth, Display.getHeight() - ad.getHeight());
        }
    };
    hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    bar = new BitmapField(DesignSizes.FanClubBar(), Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.NON_FOCUSABLE | Field.READONLY);
    hfm.add(bar);
    vvv.add(hfm);
    hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    manager = AppManager.getInstance();
    bean = manager.getBean_en();
    // System.out.println("DATE: "+ bean.getNewsDate() );

    // another try ...
    Date _date;
    Calendar _cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    _cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,
            Integer.parseInt(bean.getNewsDate().substring(0, 4)));
    _cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,
            Integer.parseInt(bean.getNewsDate().substring(5, 7)) - 1);
    _cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
            Integer.parseInt(bean.getNewsDate().substring(8, 10)));

    _date = _cal.getTime();

    DateFormat dff = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    String datedatedate = dff.formatLocal(_date.getTime());
    dateField = new LabelField(datedatedate);
    dateField.setPadding(padding);
    titleField = new LabelField(bean.getNewsTitle(), Field.FIELD_LEFT) {
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            graphics.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }

    };
    titleField.setPadding(padding);
    Font font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 9, Ui.UNITS_pt);
    titleField.setFont(font);
    bitmapField = new BitmapField(DesignSizes.newsIsLoading(),
            Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    bitmapField.setPadding(padding);
    setBitmap(bean.getImgUrl());

    articleField = new RichTextField(parser.clean(bean.getNewsArticle()),
            RichTextField.USE_TEXT_WIDTH | RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT
                    | RichTextField.READONLY);
    // bitmap field for the add bitmap
    ad = new BitmapField(DesignSizes.adBanner(), Field.FIELD_TRAILING
            | Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    // horizontal field manager to set the bitmapfield away from the
    // scrollable screen .. as its required to be only
    // on the bottom of the screen !

    admanager = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                    | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR
                    | Field.FIELD_HALIGN_MASK);

    // the other stuff title bar + action bar + itemRow + button more
    otherStuff = new VerticalFieldManager(
            VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL) {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setExtent(maxWidth, Display.getHeight() - ad.getHeight());
        }
    };
    admanager.add(ad);
    // font for the article
    Font artFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 6, Ui.UNITS_pt);
    articleField.setPadding(padding);
    articleField.setFont(artFont);
    vvv.add(dateField);
    vvv.add(titleField);
    vvv.add(bitmapField);
    vvv.add(articleField);
    add(vvv);
    add(admanager);

    switch (Display.getWidth()) {
    case 320:
        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry320());
        break;
    case 360:
        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry360());
        break;
    case 480:
        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry480());
        break;
    case 640:
        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry640());
        break;
    }


}

private void setBitmap(final String url) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub\\

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final DownLoadImage dope = new DownLoadImage(url);
            bitmap = dope.getImage();
            Bitmap resized_bitmap = bitmap;
            Bitmap tempbitmap = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth() - 20,
                    (int) ((Display.getWidth() - 20) * 0.458));
            tempbitmap.createAlpha(Bitmap.TRUE_WHITE);
            resized_bitmap.scaleInto(tempbitmap, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);
            bitmap = tempbitmap;
            bitmapField.setBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    });
}

protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
    int key = Keypad.key(keycode);
    if (key == Characters.ESCAPE) {
        try{
            this.time.cancel();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                new NewsScreen_en(status, tour));

        return true;
    }
    return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}

// =============================================================================================
    // for getting the ads ...
    // =============================================================================================
    private void loadAD(int timer) {
        System.out.println("Timer start! ");

            time = new Timer();
            task = new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    time.cancel();
                    switch (Display.getWidth()) {
                    case 320:
                        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry320());
                        break;
                    case 360:
                        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry360());
                        break;
                    case 480:
                        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry480());
                        break;
                    case 640:
                        getAd(adsBean[adCounter].getBlackberry640());
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("tik tik tik");
                }
            };
            time.schedule(task, timer * 1000);

    }

    private void getAd(final String url) {

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final DownLoadImage dope = new DownLoadImage(url);
                Bitmap bitmap = dope.getImage();
                ad.setBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });


        //for saving more memo
        switch(Integer.parseInt(adsBean[adCounter].getAdDuration())){
        case 0:
            //
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("loading ad! ");
            adCounter++ ;

            if(adCounter == adsBean.length || adCounter > adsBean.length){
            adCounter = 0;
            }
            loadAD(Integer.parseInt(adsBean[adCounter].getAdDuration()));
            break;
        }





    }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your screen scrollable add focusable elements to it. If a screen or its area does not have focusable elements then you will experience problems with scrolling this screen/area.

As an option add empty and focusable separator fields after each non-focusable field. It won't affect on the appearance of your application but will help with scrolling.

Comment: Thanks .. I did already put a null field between my fields and it worked .. I was gonna post it as a solution here but you were faster =] .. thanks again =]